# How to get sale ID from the new Paypal Sync Api

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using the new Paypal Sync Api to get all transactions in a period of time. I need to be able to refund them too.
As all our transactions are always sales I need the sale ID to refund a transaction as stated in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/refund-payments/#set-up-your-development-environment
Unfortunately I can not find anything in the transactions response which can be used as a sale ID

```
{
    "transaction_details": [

        {
            "transaction_info": {
                "paypal_account_id": "6EN7PS8P9DV6J",
                "transaction_id": "05P62542TL3758730",
                "transaction_event_code": "T0006",
                "transaction_initiation_date": "2019-07-04T12:49:55+0000",
                "transaction_updated_date": "2019-07-04T12:53:09+0000",
                "transaction_amount": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": "10.00"
                },
                "fee_amount": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": "-0.49"
                },
                "transaction_status": "S",
                "ending_balance": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": "0.00"
                },
                "available_balance": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": "0.00"
                },
                "protection_eligibility": "01"
            },
            "payer_info": {
                "account_id": "6EN7PS8P9DV6J",
                "email_address": "paypaltester3@test.de",
                "address_status": "Y",
                "payer_status": "Y",
                "payer_name": {
                    "given_name": "Tester Three",
                    "surname": "Tester Three",
                    "alternate_full_name": "Tester Three Tester Three"
                },
                "country_code": "DE"
            },
            "shipping_info": {
                "name": "Tester Three, Tester Three",
                "address": {
                    "line1": "Teststreet. 1",
                    "city": "SomeCity",
                    "country_code": "DE",
                    "postal_code": "23434"
                }
            },
            "cart_info": {
                "item_details": [
                    {
                        "item_quantity": "1",
                        "item_unit_price": {
                            "currency_code": "USD",
                            "value": "10.00"
                        },
                        "item_amount": {
                            "currency_code": "USD",
                            "value": "10.00"
                        },
                        "total_item_amount": {
                            "currency_code": "USD",
                            "value": "10.00"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "store_info": {},
            "auction_info": {},
            "incentive_info": {}
        }
    ],
    "account_number": "96B45RCG6AX3E",
    "start_date": "2019-07-03T00:00:00+0000",
    "end_date": "2019-07-04T16:00:00+0000",
    "last_refreshed_datetime": "2019-07-15T08:59:59+0000",
    "page": 1,
    "total_items": 15,
    "total_pages": 1,
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2019-07-03T00%3A00%3A00Z&end_date=2019-07-04T16%3A00%3A00Z&fields=all&page_size=500&page=1",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tested a refund call with a transactionId and with an invoiceId but both returned "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR".

Is there any way to get the sale ID by an API after the customer has completed the payment or do I have to save the sale ID in a database after creating a payment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With T0006 you are lucky, it is a simple `PayPal Checkout APIs.` transaction, it would be harder with T0002. Anyway, no the response have much more data. The example is below.
You can find it in `invoice_number`, or `invoice_id`. If only you had this data during payment creation procedures.

```
"transaction_details":[ 
      { 
         "transaction_info":{ 
            "paypal_account_id":"HHHHH",
            "transaction_id":"040404040404040",
            "transaction_event_code":"T0006",
            "transaction_initiation_date":"2019-10-31T06:21:37+0000",
            "transaction_updated_date":"2019-10-31T06:31:02+0000",
            "transaction_amount":{ 
               "currency_code":"AUD",
               "value":"96.90"
            },
            "fee_amount":{ 
               "currency_code":"AUD",
               "value":"-4.08"
            },
            "shipping_amount":{ 
               "currency_code":"AUD",
               "value":"17.90"
            },
            "transaction_status":"S",
            "transaction_subject":"Full License",
            "ending_balance":{ 
               "currency_code":"AUD",
               "value":"92.82"
            },
            "available_balance":{ 
               "currency_code":"AUD",
               "value":"92.82"
            },
            "invoice_id":"1110-US1",
            "protection_eligibility":"01"
         },
         "payer_info":{ 
            "account_id":"HHHHH",
            "email_address":"test@paypal.com",
            "address_status":"Y",
            "payer_status":"Y",
            "payer_name":{ 
               "given_name":"First",
               "surname":"Last",
               "alternate_full_name":"First Last"
            },
            "country_code":"GB"
         },
         "shipping_info":{ 
            "name":"Shaun Smith",
            "address":{ 
               "line1":"123, Some Road",
               "line2":"Shop 4",
               "city":"Melbourne",
               "country_code":"AU",
               "postal_code":"3185"
            }
         },
         "cart_info":{ 
            "item_details":[ 
               { 
                  "item_name":"Full License",
                  "item_description":"Full License",
                  "item_quantity":"1",
                  "item_unit_price":{ 
                     "currency_code":"AUD",
                     "value":"79.00"
                  },
                  "item_amount":{ 
                     "currency_code":"AUD",
                     "value":"79.00"
                  },
                  "total_item_amount":{ 
                     "currency_code":"AUD",
                     "value":"79.00"
                  },
                  "invoice_number":"1110-US1"
               }
            ]
         },
         "store_info":{ 

         },
         "auction_info":{ 

         },
         "incentive_info":{ 

         }
      },
```